# How to convert object to time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

How can I convert "2022-03-01  1:01:42 AM" to just 1:01:42?

I tried to strip just the time out and convert to datetime format, but it keeps adding the current date to the beginning. Otherwise, it doesn't properly convert to datetime format so I can plot it later. All I want is the time in datetime format.

```
def time():
    df['Time'] = df['TIME'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[1])
    df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, format = '%H:%M:%S', errors='ignore').dt.time
```

Comment: keep the datetime as it is and configure your plot to only show the time

Comment: How is this not a duplicate?

Comment: Im still lost lol

Comment: also note that if you want the data type of a pandas series to be datetime (datetime64[ns]), it cannot be "just time", it's always date and time. if you want to *display* just the time, format the datetime data to string with the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

No need to split it. just simply:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2],
                   'TIME':['2022-03-01 1:01:42 AM', '2022-03-01 12:01:42 PM']})

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.TIME, errors='ignore').dt.time
```

**Output:**

```
df.iloc[0]['Time']
Out[1]: datetime.time(1, 1, 42)
```

Comment: This was just a snippit of a data frame column. I have 4000 different times to convert. Also the dtype is still object

Comment: And what does that have to do with the solution? Just use `pd.to_datetime(df.column_name, errors='ignore').dt.time` on the column.

Comment: i need the dtype to be datetime not object

Comment: I already have 'df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, format = '%H:%M:%S', errors='ignore').dt.time'

Comment: @tozzy it is a `datetime.time` object

Answer (score 0):

How about using simple date format

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
print (now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```